# How to set DiscoveryLookupBinding.url in onvif RemoteDiscovery

Tags: android, url, xamarin, discovery, onvif

I'm trying to develop an Android APP to discover and access onvif cameras under VS2017 and Xamarin. 
By 'Add Web Reference', I added Web Reference of DeviceMgmt and RemoteDiscovery of onvif website.

For generated DeviceMgmt code, there is DeviceBinding class and when I set its url to e.g.
"http://192.168.0.22/onvif/device_service",
all functions like GetCapabilities() and GetDeviceInformation() can work.

For generated RemoteDiscovery code, I noticed there is DiscoveryLookupBinding class, but don't know how to set its url to call Probe().

I tried "239.255.255.250", but it's invalid.

If anybody has the related experience? Any ideas are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who may be interested in.

Later for DeviceMgmt and Media services, I used Xamarin-generated references code.

But for Device Discovery, I created a Binding Library (Android) to still use my old java code. And it works well.